# Exchange 2013 permission error after installing cu15

Tags: windows, permissions, exchange

I installed comulative update 15 on exchange 2013 server and all exchange admins getting error when saving in exchange management console or exchange management shell.

Console:

> Active Directory operation failed on domain.controller.com. This error
>   is not retriable. Additional information: Insufficient access rights
>   to perform the operation. Active directory response: 00002098: SecErr:
>   DSID-03150BB9, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0

Exchange management shell: (for example I tried to disable transport rule)

```
Active Directory operation failed on domain.controllercom. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Insufficient
access rights to perform the operation.
Active directory response: 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150E49, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Disable-TransportRule], ADOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=srvname,RequestId=cf69280d-fdae-48fe-8f3e-b15a621a77db,TimeStamp=12/19/2016 7:46:09 P
   M] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADOperationException] B957B670,Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.Rules.Tasks.Disable
  TransportRule
    + PSComputerName        : domain.controller.com
```

I tried to disable and enable inheritance permissions on my accont in active directory. But this fix is not working for me. Who can help me?

Comment: Did this ever work (i.e. was it working before CU15)?  Have you tried the simple stuff yet, like rebooting the Exchange server?

Comment: Yes, before CU15 it is working.

Comment: I tried rebooting.

Comment: Anything else you've tried already (helps avoid us asking/suggesting things you've already tried)?

Comment: I tried adding more groups on my account and on computer account (exchange server), I tried add organization management, exchange trusted subsystem and exchange managed availability groups

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just add exchange trusted subsystem group on exchange computer account (in active directory) member of and reboot exchange server (necessary).